Evaluate the security of the message encryption extension
I created exrension for Firefox, but i'm not really sure about it's security. Can somebody help, how my program should store permanent keys? Now i keep them in local storage encrypted, but this extension will be opensource, so It would be better to understand all problems before release
Html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    <title>Main menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="new_window">
            <img src="materials/open_in_new_24dp_E8EAED_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz24.svg" alt="open"/>
        </div>
        <div class="setting">
            <img src="materials/settings_24dp_E8EAED_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz24.svg" alt="settings"/>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="choose__action">
            <div class="choose__action__encrypt">
                encrypt
            </div>
            <div class="choose__action__decrypt">
                decrypt
            </div>
        </div>
        <label>
            <textarea class="text_input"></textarea>
        </label>
        <div class="key_input_box">
            <label class="switch">
                one-time key
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox__switcher"/>
                permanent key
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="text" class="key_input"/>
            </label>
        </div>
        <label class="output__box">
            <div class="output_text">Output</div>
            <textarea class="output" disabled></textarea>
        </label>
        <div class="send_button_box">
            <button class="operation__button">
               Convert
            </button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <div class="settings__window">
        <div class="settings__flex_block">
            <div class="settings__title">Settings</div>
            <div class="settings__exit__button">
                <img src="materials/close_24dp_E8EAED_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz24.svg" alt="close">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="settings_description">
            Warning! To avoid password brute force, we strongly recommend using a 10-character password that contains at least one digit and a special characters.
            Permanent keys are stored encrypted locally.
        </div>
        <div class="change__block">
            <div>
                <span class="settings__encryption_errors"></span>
                <input type="text" class="settings__encryption__key" placeholder="Set encryption key"/>
                <button class="encryption__key__button">Save</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="settings__decryption_errors"></span>
                <input type="text" class="settings__decryption__key" placeholder="Set decryption key"/>
                <button class="decryption__key__button">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


css:
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input, textarea{
    outline: none;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.new_window, .setting{
    cursor: pointer;
}
main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 70px 50px;
}
.choose__action{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.choose__action{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.choose__action__encrypt{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.choose__action__decrypt{
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.choose__action__encrypt.active, .choose__action__decrypt.active{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.text_input{
    margin-top: 50px;
    resize: none;
    width: 235px;
    height: 100px;
}
.key_input_box{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.key_input{
    width: 235px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.switch{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
    /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}
.checkbox__switcher{
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #c6c6c6;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(135, 97, 97, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox__switcher:checked{
    background-color: #171616;
}
.checkbox__switcher::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: .5s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
}
.checkbox__switcher:checked::before{
    left: 20px;
}
.output__box{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.output{
    resize: none;
    width: 235px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.operation__button{
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
.operation__button:hover{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.modal{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*display: flex;*/
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.saveKeyButton{
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.saveKeyButton:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.modal_background{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.modal_warning{
    font-size: 15px;
}
.settings__window{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.settings__exit__button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.settings__flex_block{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.settings__title{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana, serif;
}
.change__block{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.settings__encryption__key, .settings__decryption__key{
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
}
.encryption__key__button, .decryption__key__button{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000000;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.encryption__key__button:hover, .decryption__key__button:hover{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.settings_description{
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}


js:
let encrypt__button = document.querySelector('.choose__action__encrypt')
let decrypt__button = document.querySelector('.choose__action__decrypt')
let key_input = document.querySelector('.key_input')
let switcher = document.querySelector('.checkbox__switcher')
let new_window = document.querySelector('.new_window')
let send_button = document.querySelector('.operation__button')
let input_text = document.querySelector('.text_input')
let output_text = document.querySelector('.output')
let output_warning = document.querySelector('.output_text')
let setting__button = document.querySelector('.setting')
let settings_window = document.querySelector('.settings__window')
let settings__exit = document.querySelector('.settings__exit__button')
let settings__encryption__key = document.querySelector('.settings__encryption__key')
let settings__decryption__key = document.querySelector('.settings__decryption__key')
let encryption__key__button = document.querySelector('.encryption__key__button')
let decryption__key__button = document.querySelector('.decryption__key__button')


// Удобство и сохранение методов в локальном хранилище
if (localStorage.getItem('method')){
    if (localStorage.getItem('method') === 'decrypt'){
        decrypt__button.classList.add('active')
    } else{
        encrypt__button.classList.add('active')
    }
} else{
    encrypt__button.classList.add('active')
}
if (localStorage.getItem('key_input')){
    if (localStorage.getItem('key_input') === 'true'){
        switcher.checked = true
        key_input.disabled = true
    } else{
        switcher.checked = false
        key_input.disabled = false
    }
}

//открытие нового окна
new_window.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        browser.windows.create({
        url: "popup.html",
        type: "popup",
        width: 450,
        height: 700
    });
})

//смена методов
decrypt__button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if (encrypt__button.classList.contains('active')){
        encrypt__button.classList.remove('active');
    }
    decrypt__button.classList.add('active')
    localStorage.setItem("method", "decrypt")
})
encrypt__button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if (decrypt__button.classList.contains('active')){
        decrypt__button.classList.remove('active');
    }
    encrypt__button.classList.add('active')
    localStorage.setItem("method", "encrypt");
})
//выбор пароля
switcher.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if (switcher.checked){
        key_input.disabled = true
        localStorage.setItem('key_input', 'true')
    } else{
        key_input.disabled = false
        localStorage.setItem('key_input', 'false')
    }
})
//Кнопка настроек
setting__button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (!(settings_window.style.display === 'block')){
        settings_window.style.display = 'block'
    }
})
//Окно настроек
settings__exit.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (!(settings_window.style.display === 'none')){
        settings_window.style.display = 'none'
    }
})
//Смена постоянных ключей
encryption__key__button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (settings__encryption__key.value){
        let check = password_check(settings__encryption__key.value)
        if (check){
            saveEncryptionKeys(settings__encryption__key.value)
            settings__encryption__key.value = ''
            document.querySelector('.settings__encryption_errors').textContent = ''
        }else{
            document.querySelector('.settings__encryption_errors').textContent = 'Password contains unacceptable simbols'
        }
    }
})
decryption__key__button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (settings__decryption__key.value){
        let check = password_check(settings__decryption__key.value)
        if (check){
            saveDecryptionKeys(settings__decryption__key.value)
            settings__decryption__key.value = ''
            document.querySelector('.settings__decryption_errors').textContent = ''
        }else{
            document.querySelector('.settings__decryption_errors').textContent = 'Password contains unacceptable simbols'
        }
    }
})
//отправка данных для шифрования/дешифрования
send_button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    let method = localStorage.getItem('method') || 'encrypt';
    let key;

    if (switcher.checked === true && method === 'encrypt') {
        key = await getEncryptionKey();
        if (!key) {
            if (!(settings_window.style.display === 'block')){
                settings_window.style.display = 'block'
            }
            return;
        }
    } else if (switcher.checked === true && method === 'decrypt') {
        key = await getDecryptionKey();
        if (!key) {
            if (!(settings_window.style.display === 'block')){
                settings_window.style.display = 'block'
            }
            return;
        }
    } else {
        key = key_input.value;
    }

    let inText = input_text.value
    if (method === 'encrypt'){
        output_text.value = await encryptWithPassword(key, inText)
        output_warning.textContent = 'Output'
    } else{
        const decryptedText = await decryptWithPassword(key, inText)
        if (decryptedText === null) {
            output_text.textContent = ""
            output_warning.textContent = "Incorrect decryption key"
        } else {
            output_text.value = decryptedText
            output_warning.textContent = "Output"
        }
    }
})
//сохранение паролей в локальном хранилище
async function saveEncryptionKeys(encryptionKey) {
    const { encryptedText, iv } = await encryptText(encryptionKey);
    localStorage.setItem('encryptionKey', encryptedText);
    localStorage.setItem('encryptionIV', iv);
}
async function saveDecryptionKeys(decryptionKey) {
    const { encryptedText, iv } = await encryptText(decryptionKey);
    localStorage.setItem('decryptionKey', encryptedText);
    localStorage.setItem('decryptionIV', iv);
}
//получение паролей из локального хранилища
async function getEncryptionKey() {
    const encryptedText = localStorage.getItem('encryptionKey')
    const iv = localStorage.getItem('encryptionIV')
    if (encryptedText && iv) {
        try {
            return await decryptText(encryptedText, iv)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Ошибка расшифровки ключа:", e)
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

async function getDecryptionKey() {
    const encryptedText = localStorage.getItem('decryptionKey');
    const iv = localStorage.getItem('decryptionIV');
    if (encryptedText && iv) {
        try {
            return await decryptText(encryptedText, iv);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Ошибка расшифровки ключа:", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
//функция получения уникального ключа
async function deriveKeyFromPassword(password, salt = null) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    salt = salt || crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16))

    const keyMaterial = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw", encoder.encode(password), "PBKDF2", false, ["deriveKey"]
    );

    const cryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        { name: "PBKDF2", salt: salt, iterations: 200000, hash: "SHA-256" },
        keyMaterial,
        { name: "AES-GCM", length: 256 },
        false,
        ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );

    return { cryptoKey, salt }
}
//функция проверки пароля
function password_check(password) {
    return /^[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё0-9!@#$%^&*()_+{}\[\]:;"'<>?,./\\|~`-]+$/.test(password)
}
// функции шифрования и дешифрования на основе пароля
async function encryptWithPassword(password, plaintext) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();

    const { cryptoKey, salt } = await deriveKeyFromPassword(password);

    const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));

    const ciphertext = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        { name: "AES-GCM", iv: iv },
        cryptoKey,
        encoder.encode(plaintext)
    );

    const encryptedData = new Uint8Array(salt.length + iv.length + ciphertext.byteLength);
    encryptedData.set(salt);
    encryptedData.set(iv, salt.length);
    encryptedData.set(new Uint8Array(ciphertext), salt.length + iv.length);

    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...encryptedData)); // Конвертируем в Base64 строку
}
async function decryptWithPassword(password, encryptedText) {
    try {
        const encryptedData = Uint8Array.from(atob(encryptedText), c => c.charCodeAt(0));

        const salt = encryptedData.slice(0, 16);
        const iv = encryptedData.slice(16, 28);
        const ciphertext = encryptedData.slice(28);

        const { cryptoKey } = await deriveKeyFromPassword(password, salt);

        const decrypted = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
            { name: "AES-GCM", iv: iv },
            cryptoKey,
            ciphertext
        );

        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        return decoder.decode(decrypted);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Ошибка расшифровки: Неверный ключ или поврежденные данные.");
        return null;
    }
}

//уникальная строка для хранения паролей
async function generateFixedKey() {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const uniqueData = `${navigator.userAgent}-fixedSalt`; // создаём уникальную строку
    const keyMaterial = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw", encoder.encode(uniqueData), "PBKDF2", false, ["deriveKey"]
    );
    return await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        { name: "PBKDF2", salt: encoder.encode("fixedSalt"), iterations: 200000, hash: "SHA-256" },
        keyMaterial,
        { name: "AES-GCM", length: 256 },
        false,
        ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );
}
//шифрование текста перед отправкой в хранилище
async function encryptText(text) {
    const cryptoKey = await generateFixedKey();
    const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
    const encryptedData = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        { name: "AES-GCM", iv: iv },
        cryptoKey,
        new TextEncoder().encode(text)
    );
    return {
        encryptedText: btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(encryptedData))),
        iv: btoa(String.fromCharCode(...iv))
    };
}
async function decryptText(encryptedText, iv) {
    const cryptoKey = await generateFixedKey();
    const decryptedData = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
        { name: "AES-GCM", iv: Uint8Array.from(atob(iv), c => c.charCodeAt(0)) },
        cryptoKey,
        Uint8Array.from(atob(encryptedText), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
    );
    return new TextDecoder().decode(decryptedData);
}


I'd like to know, how keep permanet passwords and and have access without additional passwords

The naming of the css and js files suggests that you intend this code to be a popup. If so, you should say that in the question. Meanwhile, the actual code uses no extension API and is irrelevant to the question. You're asking where it's best to store passwords/keys. Are these passwords/keys set and shared by users? The wording of the question suggests that they're set by the developer (you) or an administrator and that you intend them to be hidden from the users. BTW localStorage is a very bad place to try to keep anything that you want to endure.
